# Singleton object or Use the class for some Build Configuration only - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a singleton class. This class has methods which use core data and are to be used only for some build configuration.

```
+(AClass*) singletonInstance {
static dispatch_once_t dispatchCall;
static AClass *shared=nil;

dispatch_once(&dispatchCall, ^{
shared=[[AClass alloc] init];
});
return shared;
}


-(id)init{
  self=[super init]
  if(self){
    [self initCoreData];
  }
 return self;
}
```

So, if I use the following code will this be a correct way to handle it. I think, this will be handled at compile time, so at run time it will be always nil, so any method called on

> [[AClass singletonInstance] someMethod]

will not work , As a message passed to a nil object, which will not crash but at the same time, it will not respond to that message. Also, it would not init the core data.

> Approach 1

```
+(AClass*) singletonInstance {
#if DEBUG==6
static dispatch_once_t dispatchCall;
static AClass *shared=nil;

dispatch_once(&dispatchCall, ^{
shared=[[AClass alloc] init];
});
return shared;
#else
return nil;
#endif
}
```

> Approach 2
>   I have one more helper class which has singleton method. I have this method and is used in many other classes (So, if in future if I change it to DEBUG preprocessor value to say "10", then I will have to make change at one place only). would be ok to use it over here also?

```
-(BOOL)shouldInitContent{
    #if DEBUG==6
     return YES;
    #else
     return NO;
    #endif
}

    +(AClass*) singletonInstance {
       if([[AHelperClass helperInstance] shouldInitContent]){
   static dispatch_once_t dispatchCall;
    static AClass *shared=nil;

    dispatch_once(&dispatchCall, ^{
    shared=[[AClass alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
       }else{
     return nil;
       }

    }
```

Which of the above two approaches could be efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with approach #1, because it will help you minimize the memory consumption.

In the second approach you are using two singleton instance which I doesn't recommend.